# What's the most reliable way to get the week day from a utc Date

Tags: javascript, date, utc, dayofweek

This is how I'm getting the date's week day

```
const date = new Date('2022-06-25T'+hour+':00:00.951Z')
const day1 = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { weekday: 'short' })
```

And this is how I'm constructing the date

```
`${date.getUTCDate()} ${date.toLocaleString('en-GB', { month: 'short' })} ${date.getUTCFullYear()}`
```

But apparently fails for some dates in certain hours (this is the screenshot i was sent)
[image]

If you notice the 25 of June and the 26 of June are actually Saturday and Sunday. So both date/day are not synced

After searching a bit online I found this implementation (that uses UTC function)

```
const weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
const d = new Date();
let day = weekdays[d.getUTCDay()];
```

And I Did this little script to compare the result for 25th of June

```js
const weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']

for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   const hour = i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
   const date = new Date('2022-06-25T'+hour+':00:00.951Z')
   const day1 = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { weekday: 'short', timeZone: 'Asia/Tbilisi' }) 
   const day2 = weekdays[date.getUTCDay()]
   console.log('2022-06-25 at', hour, day1, day2)
}
```

And you can see in the devtools that is not returning same day after 20h

```
2022-06-25 at 00 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 01 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 02 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 03 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 04 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 05 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 06 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 07 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 08 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 09 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 10 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 11 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 12 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 13 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 14 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 15 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 16 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 17 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 18 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 19 Sat Sat
2022-06-25 at 20 Sun Sat
2022-06-25 at 21 Sun Sat
2022-06-25 at 22 Sun Sat
2022-06-25 at 23 Sun Sat
```

So wat's the most reliable way to get the week day name?

Comment: Well, you understand how time works; the local day-of-week is not necessarily the same as the UTC day; UTC is western Europe, so at some points in time the day-of-week is not the same as in a place far to the east of there. You have to decide if what you want is the UTC day-of-week or the local day-of-week; either can be gotten reliably.

Comment: @Pointy as I'm displaying the full date that returns the `date.getUTCDate` they should be synced so I guess that I want the UTC day-of-week? ( Dates have always confused me, hehe )

Comment: Again, it depends on your application. The `.getUTCday()` method will get you what day it is *in London* for a particular date. For the exact same date object, `.getDay()` gets you the day-of-week in the local time zone where the code is running. Both days are "correct" in a sense; it just depends on what you want.

Comment: so as I'm displaying the `getUTCDate` I guess I will go for `getUTCday` this way the will print the same day/date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> new Date('2022-06-25T'+hour+':00:00.951Z')
> ```

Is parsed as UTC (provided *hour* is padded to 2 digits), so far so good.

> ```
> date.toLocaleString('en-US', { weekday: 'short', timeZone: 'Asia/Tbilisi' })
> ```

Gets the local day name in Asia/Tbilisi, which is +4 all year round. So for UTC times after 20:00, the local day will be the next day. To get the UTC day, use `timeZone: 'UTC'` in the options, e.g.

```js
// Current UTC day
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('en',{weekday: 'short', timeZone: 'UTC'}));
```

Note that UTC isn't a timezone, it's actually the opposite, it's a standard that defines a datum from which all offsets (and hence timezones) are measured.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2022, 5, 25, 3, 23, 16, 738));
const weekday = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', {  weekday: 'short', timeZone: 'UTC' }).format(date)

console.log(weekday)
```

Comment: That returns the local day name, not UTC. You need to add `timeZone:'UTC'` to the options.